# iTunes on iOS 7 Crashing

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios

Since Friday 9/20/2013, when I try to open iTunes on my iPhone 4s (running iOS 7), it crashes.  I was able to open it to do a search and purchase a song, but after it started downloading, it crashed.  Every time I try to re-open it, it crashes after a couple of seconds.  I've tried unloading it from memory and that doesn't fix it.  I also completely shutdown and powered on the phone, but that doesn't fix it either.

I can't believe completely wiping my phone would be the only way to fix this; any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have many other levers other than a full backup and I erasing all content and settings as a general remedy, but I would probably try the following for resorting to a wipe:

1. Check the usage and delete some content so that you have at least one gigabyte of free space
2. Signout of iTunes Home sharing and iTunes match
3. Sign out of the App Store
4. Make sure the date and time are set correctly or automatically set
5. Put the device in airplane mode, then power down and start back up while in airplane mode

If the music app is still misbehaving after removing all the network influences it might be something about your iTunes library on the device. You could also try using iTunes to blow away all the music.

Also, since you just made a purchase from the iTunes stores, Apple support should be able to help you with that purchase (and the problems using it as a result of the purchase).  http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific.  It's the iTunes Store app that is crashing, not the music app.

Comment: The two are tied, I'd still perform the same steps. You'll need to sign back in once you clear things - perhaps also try buying a free app (or paid) before you try to buy music or re-download the purchase.

Comment: Does seem network related. After following all of your steps, I was able to see my purchases through iTunes and verify that the song I bought does appear there.  However, now I'm on the search page and I just entered a random artist's name, and I'm getting "Cannot connect to iTunes store".  Ugh.

Answer (score -5):

easy open music,select store problem solved

Comment: It would be useful if you elaborate on the steps, what it solved for you and so on.